# Codeigniter 3.1.6 HMVC - unable to delect controller located in subfolders

Tags: codeigniter

Directory structure is like :
application/modules/data/controllers/ecard/Ecard.php

Url site-name.com/index.php/data/ecard is not working.

But same URl was working in Codeigniter 2.2.0 HMVC.

Can anyone suggest solution to this problem?

Comment: you need probably an update take a look @ https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads/

Comment: I am using same code, but still its not working.

Comment: how do you call the controller in your browser ?

Comment: http://site-name.com/index.php/data/ecard

Comment: and is `/data/ecard/ecard/` working ?